# how to write an attribute to a root attribute using xml and xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIxWh.jpg)I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to write and attribute to a root attribute.

Right now I have it as :

```
 Dim XMLOUtput= ",?xml version""1.0"" ecoding = ""utf-8"" ?>"
 xmlOutput= xmloutput + "<company=" 
 xmloutput = xmloutput + "xmlns = ""http:..www.w3schools.com"""
```

My issue is that I want it to show as `<company:name`  when displayed. How do I code for that ?

Also i would like to keep it as the `xmloutput`.

I have tried `xmloutput = xmloutput + "<company="name""` that didn't work

I have tried a couple different things as well and they didn't work either.

Comment: Your question is very unclear: What is not working? `ecoding` or `encoding`? `http:..www` or `http://www`? Why start with `",?xml` vs. `<xml `?

Comment: i want it to say Company:Name  but i can't get it to work

Comment: I must be missing something ... Did you try `xmlOutput = xmlOutput + "<Company:Name"`

Comment: yes and it didn't work  it just shows  <company

Comment: basically the company is the root attribute and the Name is an attribute of the root and i can't get it to act like it.

Comment: Which language is this in? VB.NET?

Comment: im writing in aspx.net

Comment: What are you doing to 'show' xmloutput?

Comment: @KaceyLynnHuffman `company` as in `<company:name` is a namespace prefix. You must have the prefix declaration as well, something like `xmlns:company="whatever"`.

Comment: I added a picture of what i am doing ... the <company =  in the first line i can't figure out how to get it to display as company:name on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to write an XML document using string concatenation and to get it right. I would use an XML serializer, which will do most of the difficult stuff for you. 
I assume that you're using VB, or one of the other .Net languages. You will almost certainly have an XML library available, and you should use it.